# How to copy file with composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3

After composer finishes installing everything, I want it to move Users.php from `zzother/Users.php` to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php`

I have the following in composer but it didn't copy the file after `composer install`

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate",
            "php -r \"copy('zzother/User.php', 'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php');\""
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of each file and especially the target directory?

Comment: Don't overwrite vendor files directly. There are many methods to utilize your file as opposed to their file through service providers, facades and use statements.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? There is probably a better solution. Read about [XY problems here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Can you please explain how?  I think that would be a useful answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overriding one of your package's file, I suppose you are looking for something else.

In your case, I would use simple patch. **It will download the package and override the `User` class code with your changes.**

Available in composer thanks to package: https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches